# PHP flush() function not working

Tags: php, flush

I am trying to echo output of script while its still running. gzip compression is off. I am using Firefox 22

In php.ini i set following values :

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
zlib.output_compression_level = -1
zlib.output_compression = Off
output_buffering = 0
implicit_flush = true
```

I am using this example :

```
<?php
ob_end_flush ();
//start buffering
ob_start ();

echo str_pad ( '', 1024 ); // minimum start for Safari 
for ( $i = 10; $i > 0; $i --) {
    echo str_pad ( "$i<br>\n", 8 );
    ob_flush ();
    flush ();
    sleep ( 1 );
}
?>
```

i also tried to replace

```
echo str_pad ( '', 1024 );
```

with

```
echo str_pad ( '', 4096 );
```

but it didnt work. There are lots of topic about this issue but there is no guaranteed way to make this work and other solutions didnt work for me.

Is there any method to debug this issue and find the solution?

I dont want to use ajax because script also needs to be able to used by cron.

Comment: Which server are you using? Apache?

Comment: yes it was Apache, currently problem solved, see my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was php handler, i was using suphp, now i changed it to fastcgi and problem solved.